# IDLE2 and Python2.7 in BUSTER

Tags: raspbian-buster, python-2.x

I use a "old" program, running in python2.7 Unfortunately i am not able to convert it to python3!

Now I shold run this programm in BUSTER on a rasperry 4.

As there is no more IDLE2 for Python2, I installed sudo apt-get install idle But idle-python3.7 was installed !!

In the main menue editor I find "Python 2 (IDLE)" and "Python 3 (IDLE)". But if I open "Python 2 (IDLE)", a IDLE version 3.7.3 is opening. (If I open "Python 3 (IDLE)" I get the same IDLE version 3.7.3)

I need some help to get a IDLE for Pythone 2 running.

Thanks Hermann

Comment: Why can't you convert it to Python3? You don't need IDLE installed. What happens from a command line 'python program.py' ?

Answer (score 1):

[Support of Python2 has ended at 2020-01-01](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/) so you are out of luck to get support on up to date distributions like Raspbian Buster. You should really take the effort to [convert your old script to Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html). There a no limitations known that it cannot be done. You may also consider to downgrade to an older distribution like Raspbian Stretch but this cannot run on a Raspberry Pi 4B. You see, also this has no future.

Answer (score 1):

`idle` is a synonym for `idle-python3.7`. If you need the 2.7 package, run

```
sudo apt install idle-python2.7
```

Comment: sudo apt install idle-python2.7   really worked!